# How to call non-static method?

Tags: java

I am writing this code to determine whether a number is even or odd, if it's even it returns true, if it's not then it returns false.  the given syntax is public boolean isEven(int n) so I can't change it.

```
class Main { // Given
  public boolean isEven(int n)   { // Given
   if(n % 2==0){// I wrote from this
   return true;
   }else{
     return false;
   }

  }
  isEven(2); //To this

}
```

When I try to run this, I get these errors:

```
exit status 1
Main.java:14: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
  isEven(2);
  ^
Main.java:14: error: illegal start of type
  isEven(2);
         ^
2 errors
```

Comment: You dropped a random method call `isEven(2)` in the middle of your class body. It doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 1):

To invoke an *instance* method (one that’s not `static`), you need an instance on which to invoke:

```
class Main {
    public boolean isEven(int n) {
        return n % 2==0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main obj = new Main();
        System.out.println(obj.isEven(2));
    }
}
```

Note also the simplification of your code to a single statement.

Comment: Can you go in depth as to why you did Main obj = new Main()?

Comment: `new Main()` creates an instance of your class, which is (somewhat confusingly) named `Main`.

Comment: Isn't it better to make the method `isEven()` also static?

Comment: Yes it is, but the OP asked how to call a non-static method, so the answer does accurately answer the question.